# Почему при использовании Stream.sorted(Comparator.comparing()) удаляется первый элемент потока?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, java-stream

Java 8

Данный код:

```
Stream.iterate(new int[]{1, 1}, c -> new int[]{++c[0], ++c[1]}).limit(3)
        .forEach(c -> System.out.print(Arrays.toString(c) + " "));
```

Выдаёт следующий результат:

```
[1, 1] [2, 2] [3, 3]
```

Но если добавить сортировку с компаратором:

```
Stream.iterate(new int[]{1, 1}, c -> new int[]{++c[0], ++c[1]}).limit(3)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(c -> c[0]))
        .forEach(c -> System.out.print(Arrays.toString(c) + " "));
```

Получаем следующие значения:

```
[2, 2] [3, 3] [3, 3]
```

Не могу понять Почему первое значение пропадает, а последнее при этом повторяется 2 раза. Если limit указать 1, то и в первом и во втором случае выведется [1, 1].

Comment: вы инкрементами меняете предыдущий элемент потока. во втором стриме текущий элемент будет сравниваться с таким же, уже увеличенным, предыдущим. поменяйте ++с[i] на c[i]+1. а вообще это плохая практика.

Comment: @Serodv Да вы правы, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Из офф. доки по Stream.iterate:

```
The first element (position 0) in the Stream will be the provided seed. For n > 0, the element at position n, will be the result of applying the function f to the element at position n - 1.
```

Т.е. для первого элемента будет возвращен seed

Для остальных - результат применения функции к предыдущему параметру. Но у тебя инкрементом изменяется этот предыдущий параметр:
было {1,1} после инкремента он стал {2,2}. Последний элемент не увеличивается, потому что к нему не применяется инкремент.